# SQLiteConstraintException dont go inside catch

Tags: android, sqlite, exception, insert, sql-update

When I run that code I have inside the db.insert an exception:

```
08-29 15:40:17.519: E/SQLiteDatabase(3599): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column date is not unique (code 19)
```

Which is normal, because I already have that value as a key.
So in that case I do a catch of `SQLiteConstraintException` but I never get inside the catch when I run the code.

What am I doing wrong?

```
           try {
                db.insert(TABLE_STATISTICS, null, values);
            } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
                Log.d("entered", "entered the exception");
                ContentValues valuesUp = new ContentValues();
                valuesUp.put((isMT ? KEY_MT : KEY_MO), change); 
                db.update(TABLE_STATISTICS, valuesUp, KEY_DATE + "=?",
                        new String[] { message_date });
            }
```

Thank you.

the whole log:

```
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828): Error inserting MO=0 date=2012-08-08 MT=1
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column date is not unique (code 19)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:775)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at xx.xxx.xxx.xx.xxxx.StatisticsHolderDay.updateCounterNextStep(StatisticsHolderDay.java:124)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at xx.xxx.xxx.xx.xxxx.StatisticsHolderDay.updateCounter(StatisticsHolderDay.java:102)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at xx.xxx.xxx.xx.xxxx.LastMonthActivity.onStart(LastMonthActivity.java:146)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1163)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5018)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2032)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-29 15:55:55.870: E/SQLiteDatabase(3828):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the error is from this insert? Post the whole Log please.

Comment: @iturki updated the main question with the whole Log.
StatisticsHolderDay.java:124 is the like where I do the insert on the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `db.insertOrThrow()`  instead.