# How to handle SQLiteConstraintException inside a content provider

Tags: java, android, try-catch, android-sqlite

I am using a content provider to read/write from a database that allows a user to organize prescriptions. Currently, I am implementing a DialogFragment that allows the user to enter a new medication. The dialog contains two EditTexts, one for strength, and one for medication name.

The table is designed so that (name, strength) is a unique key. Here is my insert method:

```
public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
    long _id; // Value used for inserts.
    Uri returnUri;

    switch(match){
        case MEDICATION:
            _id = db.insert(PMContract.MedicationEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            if(_id > 0)
                returnUri = PMContract.MedicationEntry.buildMedicationUri(_id);
            else
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Failed to insert row into: " + uri);
            break;
        default:
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unknown uri: " + uri);
    }
```

As you can guess, if the user inputs a name and strength that already exist, an SQLiteConstraintException occurs. However, all I do here is throw an UnsupportedOperationException, something that I learned from a tutorial on content providers.

What I would like to do, is handle the situation specifically where a duplicate key is entered, so I can relay that information to the user (likely via a Toast).

I have tried adding a try/catch to where I make the insert call:

```
try{
    getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(PMContract.MedicationEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);
} catch(SQLiteConstraintException e){
}
```

But SQLiteConstraintException is not the one that is caught, but instead an UnsupportedOperationException.

How can I adjust the ContentProvider code so that I know when I have a ConstraintException, and treat everything else as an UnsupportedOperationException?

**EDIT**

I have tried to wrap a try/catch block around the db.insert call:

```
case MEDICATION:
    try {
        _id = db.insert(PMContract.MedicationEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    } catch(SQLiteConstraintException e){
        String s = e.getMessage();
    } catch(Exception e1){
        String s1 = e1.getMessage();
    }

    if(_id > 0)
        returnUri = PMContract.MedicationEntry.buildMedicationUri(_id);
    else
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Failed to insert row into: " + uri);
    break;
```

And I used the debugger to see the exception that was being thrown by `db.insert()`. However, the debugger didn't hit a breakpoint in *either* of the catch blocks, even though the error text was printed in the logcat. I'm not sure why an exception is printed to the logcat but the debugger doesn't hit those breakpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying Ian's suggestion and editing my question, I realized I was having the same problem as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178633/sqliteconstraintexception-dont-go-inside-catch?rq=1).

Changing the line of code to `db.insertOrThrow()` caused the ConstraintException to be thrown if it happened, and I was able to catch that in the DialogFragment:

```
// In the ContentProvider
_id = db.insertOrThrow(PMContract.MedicationEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

// In the Dialog Fragment
try{
    getActivity().getContentResolver().insert(PMContract.MedicationEntry.CONTENT_URI, values);
    dismiss();
} catch(SQLiteConstraintException e){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "A medication with this name and strength already exists.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} catch(UnsupportedOperationException uoe){
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Unable to insert new medication.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of throwing an exception, return `null` as your `Uri` - then you can check the result of the `insert()` call - if you get a `null` return value, you know it was a constraint issue.

Comment: I thought about something like that, but if I have a null Uri it could still be *any* SQLiteException, couldn't it?

Comment: No, catch only the `SQLiteConstraintException` within your `insert()` method and return `null` only in those cases.

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to catch the exception. I've added a small code snippet to the question to demonstrate what I tried.